# Whether there is something similar to strip_tags in Java?

Tags: java, android

We have a function [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) in PHP which would strip all the tags and also you can exempt certain tags from being stripped out..

My question is whether there is anything similar in Java??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try using the [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) library. That API provides a [`clean` method](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#clean%28java.lang.String,%20org.jsoup.safety.Whitelist%29):

For examples, have a look over here: [Sanitize untrusted HTML](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/whitelist-sanitizer):

```
String unsafe = 
  "<p><a href='http://example.com/' onclick='stealCookies()'>Link</a></p>";

String safe = Jsoup.clean(unsafe, Whitelist.basic());

// now: <p><a href="http://example.com/" rel="nofollow">Link</a></p>
```

Comment: So by using whitelist I can add my own tags that can be exempted right?

In the above text,I want only <P> tags and want all other tags removed so what should do in that case?

Whether I should use addtags method on the whitelist?

Comment: Yup. You can for instance start with a `WhiteList.none` and do `addTags("P")` to create such white list.

Answer (score 1):

Use can try JSoup. It's open source and available for [download](http://jsoup.org/).

http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html

Comment: To quote the page you link to: *"Rather than interacting directly with a Cleaner object, generally see the clean methods in Jsoup."*

Answer (score 1):

The OWASP Anit-Samy project does that (and a lot more) https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_AntiSamy_Project

For simpler validation use the ESAPI Validator http://owasp-esapi-java.googlecode.com/svn/trunk_doc/latest/org/owasp/esapi/Validator.html